# Option menu alignment issue tkinter

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

I am trying to have two dropdown lists bellow two labels stating what they are. The problem is whenever i run it the second list is offset to the left. This takes place in the setupPage section and looks like so:
[image of the issue](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nayWr.png)

I have tried lots of combinations of sticky to no avail. Any help would be appreciated.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

def startPage(root):
        content = ttk.Frame(root) #frame for plaing everything into
        #frame = ttk.Frame(content, borderwidth=5, relief="sunken", width=200, height=100) #fram for plaxing images
        lbl1 = ttk.Label(content, text="Is this a new or existing site?",font=("arial",12)) #setup of label for screen 1

        yesvar = BooleanVar() #variables for check boxes later on
        novar = BooleanVar()    
        yesvar.set(False)
        novar.set(False)

        one = ttk.Checkbutton(content, text="Yes", variable=yesvar, onvalue=True) #check buttons setup
        two = ttk.Checkbutton(content, text="No", variable=novar, onvalue=True)
        ok = ttk.Button(content, text="New", command = nextPage)    #setup for buttons screen 1
        cancel = ttk.Button(content, text="Existing")

        content.grid(column=0, row=0)   #intilises content 
        #frame.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3, rowspan=2)
        lbl1.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3,pady=10,padx=10) #places the label asking the question with a gap either side for the window bindings
        #name.grid(column=3, row=1, columnspan=2)
        #one.grid(column=0, row=3)
        #two.grid(column=1, row=3)
        ok.grid(column=0, row=1,pady=10,padx=10)     #places yes button 10 away from each edge
        cancel.grid(column=1, row=1,pady=10,padx=10) #as above

def setupPage(root):
            content = ttk.Frame(root) #frame for plaing everything into
            #frame = ttk.Frame(content, borderwidth=5, relief="sunken", width=200, height=100) #fram for plaxing images
            lbl1 = ttk.Label(content, text="Select meterial 1",font=("arial",12)) #setup of label for screen 1
            lbl2 = ttk.Label(content, text = "Select meterial 2" ,font = ("arial",12))
            content.grid(column=0, row=0)
            lbl1.grid(column=0, row=0,columnspan=1, pady=10,padx=10)
            lbl2.grid(column=1,row=0,columnspan=1,pady=10,padx=10)
            clicked = StringVar()
            clicked.set("lo2")
            clicked2 = StringVar()
            clicked2.set("lo2")
            drop2 = OptionMenu(root, clicked2, "lo2", "mo3", "Lo2+mo3")
            drop = OptionMenu(root, clicked, "lo2", "mo3", "Lo2+mo3")
            drop.grid(column=0, row=1,pady=10,padx=10,sticky=NW)
            drop2.grid(column=1, row=1,pady=10,padx=10,sticky=NW)

def nextPage():
        global pagenum, root
        for widget in root.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        if pagenum == 1:
            setupPage(root)
            pagenum = 2
        else :
            startPage(root)
            pagenum = 1

startPage(root)
pagenum = 1
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: The parent of the two `OptionMenu` should be `content` instead of `root`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The parent of the labels and the OptionMenus are different.
Changing the parents to root instead of content seems to work

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk()

def startPage(root):
        print("oi")
        content = ttk.Frame(root) #frame for plaing everything into
        #frame = ttk.Frame(content, borderwidth=5, relief="sunken", width=200, height=100) #fram for plaxing images
        lbl1 = ttk.Label(content, text="Is this a new or existing site?",font=("arial",12)) #setup of label for screen 1

        yesvar = BooleanVar() #variables for check boxes later on
        novar = BooleanVar()    
        yesvar.set(False)
        novar.set(False)

        one = ttk.Checkbutton(content, text="Yes", variable=yesvar, onvalue=True) #check buttons setup
        two = ttk.Checkbutton(content, text="No", variable=novar, onvalue=True)
        ok = ttk.Button(content, text="New", command = nextPage)    #setup for buttons screen 1
        cancel = ttk.Button(content, text="Existing")

        content.grid(column=0, row=0)   #intilises content 
        #frame.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3, rowspan=2)
        lbl1.grid(column=0, row=0, columnspan=3,pady=10,padx=10) #places the label asking the question with a gap either side for the window bindings
        #name.grid(column=3, row=1, columnspan=2)
        #one.grid(column=0, row=3)
        #two.grid(column=1, row=3)
        ok.grid(column=0, row=1,pady=10,padx=10)     #places yes button 10 away from each edge
        cancel.grid(column=1, row=1,pady=10,padx=10) #as above

def setupPage(root):
            #content = ttk.Frame(root) #frame for plaing everything into
            #frame = ttk.Frame(content, borderwidth=5, relief="sunken", width=200, height=100) #fram for plaxing images
            lbl1 = ttk.Label(root, text="Select meterial 1",font=("arial",12)) #setup of label for screen 1
            lbl2 = ttk.Label(root, text = "Select meterial 2" ,font = ("arial",12))
            #content.grid(column=0, row=0)
            lbl1.grid(column=0, row=0,columnspan=1, pady=10,padx=10)
            lbl2.grid(column=1,row=0,columnspan=1,pady=10,padx=10)
            clicked = StringVar()
            clicked.set("lo2")
            clicked2 = StringVar()
            clicked2.set("lo2")
            drop2 = OptionMenu(root, clicked2, "lo2", "mo3", "Lo2+mo3")
            drop = OptionMenu(root, clicked, "lo2", "mo3", "Lo2+mo3")
            drop.grid(column=0, row=1,pady=10,padx=10,sticky=NW)
            drop2.grid(column=1, row=1,pady=10,padx=10,sticky=NW)

def nextPage():
        print("oi2")
        global pagenum, root
        for widget in root.winfo_children():
            widget.destroy()
        if pagenum == 1:
            print("oi3")
            setupPage(root)
            pagenum = 2
        else :
            startPage(root)
            pagenum = 1

startPage(root)
pagenum = 1
root.mainloop()
```